# Como enviar strings na URL via JS ou jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como faço para transformar uma string,  ex: `minha string` em `minha+string` para enviar na URL? Pode ser em JS ou jQuery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Atente ao padrão

A codificação de caracteres para enviar em uma URL ou no corpo de uma requisição não é tão simples e pode variar conforme o caso. Se o problema fosse apenas com a URL, uma simples substituição resolveria, mas existem padrões.

## Use `encodeURIComponent()`, com cuidado

Como já disse o Antonio Carlos na outra resposta, você **deve** utilizar a função [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Porém, enquanto `encodeURIComponent` transforma todos os caracteres especiais para o formato necessário, alguns poucos símbolos são ignorados: `!`, `'`, `(`, `)` e `*`.

### Codificando os caracteres adicionais

A [documentação da Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) dá um exemplo de como "corrigir" isso e aderir melhor à especificação de caracteres ([RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)):

```
function fixedEncodeURIComponent(str) {
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) {
    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
  });
}
```

### Codificando espaços para `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Adicionalmente, se você está fazendo uma requisição do tipo `POST` e o formato de codificação do corpo é `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, então para de adequar ao padrão você deve ainda substituir os espaços codificados com `%20` pelo sinal de soma (`+`).

Exemplo:

```
function toFormUrlEncoded(str) {
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) {
    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
  }).replace(/%20/g, "+");
}
```

## Use apenas nos valores dos parâmetros

Outro detalhe importante é que você não pode usar `encodeURIComponent` na URL inteira, mas deve usar em cada valor de parâmetro. Por exemplo:

```
var url = '/destino?param=' + encodeURIComponent(valorParametro);
```

Ou melhor ainda, use uma rotina "corrigida":

```
var url = '/destino?param=' + toFormUrlEncoded(valorParametro);
//ajax post
```

## Cuidado com `encodeURI`

Para codificar uma URL inteira, existe a função [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI). Em tese, ela deveria codificar a URL já pronta ao invés de um parâmetro, mas ela não codifica caracteres de controle como `?` e `&`.

Então não é muito confiável, pois se você tiver algo como `param=eu & você` vai ter problemas a rotina não tem como diferenciar um `&` enquanto legítimo separador de parâmetros e enquanto parte do valor de um parâmetro.

Answer (score 5):

Normalmente o que se faz para enviar uma string através da URL é utilizar a função `encodeURIComponent()`, como no exemplo:

Código:

```
var uri = "http://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
var res = encodeURIComponent(uri);
```

Resultado:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab
```

Porém, note que ao invés de `+` ele coloca o código `%20` no lugar do espaço.

Outra opção é usar a função `encodeURI()`, quem tem efeito similar, porém não substitui: `, / ? : @ & = + $ #`.

Fonte: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp

Answer (score 4):

Para além do que já foi respondido pelas outras duas respostas, acerca do uso de `encodeURIComponent()` para escapar caracteres potencialmente prigosos ou que atrapalham eu costumo usar funções para criar uma strng de um objeto com dados a enviar.

Por exemplo:

```
function prepareData(data) {
    return Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
        return [key, data[key]].join('=');
    }).join('&');
}

function parseURI(str) {
    var data = {};
    str.split('&').forEach(function(keyValue){
        var parts = keyValue.split('=');
        data[parts[0]] = parts[1];
    });
    return data;
}
```

a função `prepareData` converte objetos numa *query string*, ou seja de `{foo: 'bar'}` em `foo=bar`. Na função falta o `?` que inicia a query string, eu prefiro juntá-lo à  parte.

A outra faz o oposto, usado no lado do cliente para ler a *query string* do URL, usando assim:

```
var object = parseURI(location.search.slice(1));
```

Comment: Sem brincadeira, sua participação aqui no site dava um livro *"Truques e troques, JavaScript de cima em baixo, por Sergio Crisostomo"*. Bloody ninja :)

Comment: @brasofilo :) A minha filosofia é _"fake it till you make it"_, tudo o que sei hoje fui aprendendo aqui, e com outras comunidades. Daí ter gosto em continuar a partilhar.